# How to transform a string into timestamp in DataStage?

Tags: datastage

I read data from a csv file,and I get a string like "2010-7-3",
I can't transform this data into timestamp,because it not like "2010-07-03"

What should I do?Is there a stage could handle this?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the date format? Something like `StringToTimestamp(DSLink.MY_STRING_COL,"%yyyy-%m-%d")` ?

Comment: but,there are still some of data like "2010-12-30 12:30:10"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the transformer, set up three stage variables - year, month and day. Their respective values should be as follows

```
Field(InputLink.string_date, "-", 1)
Right("0" : Field(InputLink.string_date, "-", 2), 2)
Right("0" : Field(InputLink.string_date, "-", 3), 2)
```

Then use this in the output column:

```
StringToTimestamp(year : month : day : "000000", "%yyyy%mm%dd%hh%nn%ss")
```

Comment: I use the java stage and handle that problem by java code,I haven't try your solution,but thank you all the same.